# Selecting and rendering a Django template inclusion tag depending on a variable value

Tags: django, templates

One advantage of the `{% include "xyz.html" %}` method of embedding a sub-template, is you can determine which template [in a variable‌](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)​, eg, `{% include template_name %}`, where `template_name` is the variable holding the name of the template.

Is there any way to do this with an inclusion tag? Or any other approach to incuding some code with an `include`? Is the best way to put an inclusion tag within the template you're including? Eg, in the top level template have {% include template_name %} then nested within the template pointed to by `template_name` have {% load poll_extras %} {% show_results poll %}. Or is the best way using a [fully custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#advanced-custom-template-tags)? Essentially I want an `include`, whose snippet is itself named in a variable, with some custom Python code behind.

I want to create a dashboard interface with configurable elements, a bit like Qlikview or Business Objects, where the end user can define graphs or tables for their dashboard.

`{% include template_name %}` is nearly ample, but I also need a little processing in Python, for example to reshape and format data for a Javascript graphing animation control, or to provide dynamic client-side unit conversion, or drill-down links.

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Are you looking for the simplest way to implement something like `{% show_results poll "xyz.html" %}`?

Comment: Great question thanks - I've added to my OP.